# Angular 2 read JSON via HTTP

Tags: angularjs, json, http, electron

I'm new to Angular 2 and javascript in general and I'm trying to read some JSON via HTTP-request. I'm following this tutorial: https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-2-introduction-to-new-http-module-1278499db2a0

I am trying to run this example using **Electron.**

I had to make some minor changes to source code in order to get no errors when running `npm run build` like change:

`<my-person *ng-for="#person of people"`

to

`<my-person *ngFor="let person of people"`

etc. After I made these minor changes, I got it built with no errors and then ran with `npm run electron`

And here comes the problem; nothing really shows up in the view and I have no idea why not. If I activate **Chrome DevTools** with adding `win.openDevTools();` to main.js I can get console open and see that constructor of class App prints "completed" to console, so it would seem like everything is going right in the background but for some reason nothing shows up in the view.

[image: mainview]

If I change

```
export class App {
  people : any;
  constructor(peopleService:PeopleService) {
    peopleService.people
        .subscribe(
            people => this.people = people,
            error => console.error('Error: ' + error),
            () => console.log('completed!')
        );
  }
```

to

```
..
() => console.log('this.people')
..
```

I can see object printed in the console containing all three people, which are defined in `people.json` like this

```
[
  {"id": 1, "name": "Brad"},
  {"id": 2, "name": "Jules"},
  {"id": 3, "name": "Jeff"}
]
```

You can see whole project in my GitHub here: https://github.com/MikPak/ngNews

Please help me with this one to get things started. 
Later on I would like to fetch JSON-data (news) from external server and display them in the view but I have to get this solved first.

Comment: running your project without electron works fine. so it's sth about the configuration of electron i guess.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I got this working with @Apostolos advice though. :)

Comment: this was my comment before finding out what was wrong actually and posting the solution, hehe :)

Comment: Oh lol, haha.. these snoozy mornings you know.. ;p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

```
<script src="../node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
```

to your app/index.html file and remove

```
  'rxjs',
  'reflect-metadata',
```

from your angular2 entry in webpack.config.js file.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm now. Could you also please explain a bit what these scripts actually do? I read a bit about each of these scripts from google but I don't really get it why adding these things got it working and why it didn't work before adding them and removing 2 lines from webpack.config.js.

Comment: these are the default js that even the smallest angular 2 app should have according to angular's guide. es6 are ECMAScript 6 compatibility shims. zone.js is for creating zones (contexts may sound more familiar to you) and reflect refers to https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-reflection, i think. maybe you dont need to remove these lines, havent tried it with these 2 lines actually!